# Radio buttons accessibility, unable to tab to radiogroup with a checked disabled value

Tags: html, forms, input, accessibility

I encountered a problem, where one radio button group is dependant on other state, which caused a disabled radio button to be selected. This is not a problem when selecting another value in the radio button group with the mouse for example, but it seems it is impossible to tab to the radio button group now. I realise that I maybe should not let this happen, but I think it is strange that you can build radio button group that you cannot change by keyboard alone. Here is a simple example:

```html
<input type="radio" disabled checked name="test" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="4">
```

Is there something I can do to "fix" this behaviour, or does anyone have a good way to handle these edge cases, or how to code if differently all together to avoid this issue?

Comment: As Adam points out, this is just an odd consequence of how radio buttons work. Best bet likely is to re-enable that radiobutton when you select it, to avoid this case (and perhaps re-disable it when selection moves elsewhere, if you want to prevent it from being re-selected manually).

Comment: I can confirm that this is still an issue on Chrome v114. Probably other browsers too?!

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a browser issue, although i'm not sure what would be the expected bahaviour.

The problem is that when you have a radio group, the keyboard goes to the selected element. If this element is disabled, then the focus will jump the whole radio group even if the other one are not disabled.

One "fix" would be to avoid the problem by dissociating the radio buttons in two groups and relying on some javascript code to let them appear as a whole group. You can also reimplement the whole radio button feature by using aria role="radio" on 4 div elements.

It's also possible to ask and wait for the bug to be fixed.

Comment: 'You can also reimplement the whole radio button feature by using aria role="radio" on 4 div elements.' - I'd advise caution here; you'd also need to implement appropriate keyboard support, and ensure that the aria-selected is updated appropriately, and test that the whole lot works in at least a couple of screenreader/browser combinations. Using aria instead of native elements is best avoided unless absolutely necessary!